# MATCH(title) AGAINST('test 11' IN BOOLEAN MODE) can't search number

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title) AGAINST('test 11' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS     Score 
FROM search_table 
WHERE `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
AND MATCH(title) AGAINST('test 11' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY  `score`  DESC ,`date`  DESC
```

This query is not working for the number and only returns results related with the test. There are rows with 11, but nothing is returned when I search for 11.

Comment: `11` is too short to be indexed - check with `select @@global.innodb_ft_min_token_size, @@global.ft_min_word_len;`